# Which LAN driver should I use for Asus F5Z?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

A friend of mine asked me to re-install his Asus F5Z notebook with Windows XP.

I installed successfully all drivers from [Asus driver download site](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?modelname=F5Z&SLanguage=en-us). Everything is working fine but the Ethernet driver. The installation of Lan Driver for Windows XP finishes with strange message "Please shutdown & plug Realtech PCI-e card to complete the installation.

Not sure if it matters but OnChip SATA is in 'Native IDE' mode . The original one with Vista was 'IDE -> AHCI mode'.

Any idea how I can make the LAN adapter to work under Windows XP?

[image: tech spec]

## Update1

So 'Everest Ultimate' found the NIC  under `network adapters` The html report even gives details like (see below). On the other hand Windows Device manager displays Ethernet Controller under Other devices with yellow exclamation mark.

```
[ Network adapters / Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC - Packet Scheduler Miniport ]

    Device Properties:
        Driver Description      Realtek RTL8168C(P)/8111C(P) PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet NIC - Packet Scheduler Miniport
        Driver Date     7/1/2001
        Driver Version      5.1.2535.0
        Driver Provider     Microsoft
        INF File    netpsa.inf
        Hardware ID     ms_pschedmp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Everest Ultimate to get the exact Network Chip in your Laptop, then you can search for a specific driver. Everest has a Trial Version (30 days), that's enough for your problem.
(e.g. http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/EVEREST-Ultimate-Edition.shtml)

Then go to Devices -> Windows Devices -> Unknown Devices and you will find the PCI Device Name in the Info Field.

Update 1:
Then use for e.g. [this](http://www.realtek.cz/realtek-download.php?realtek=RTL8168CP_8111CP&system=1) driver from the official Realtek Page (I know the page looks terrible). The first Option should work fine.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you. What is confusing for me is that the official Asus driver doesn't work. Strange, isn't it.

Comment: I had a similar problem ones with an old computer, sometimes they just mess up. Try Everest, was the tipp from a friend. :)

Comment: @gyger: please see Update I

Comment: @Radek Added an Update

Comment: I tried the latest driver from Realtek.com last night (from 2010) it didn't work. I'll try yours...

Comment: @gyger:didn't work :-(

Comment: Oh, really sorry. That's where my wisdom finishes.

Comment: nothing I tried worked under Win XP. The NIC works smoothly under linux..

Comment: That's crzy, I don't know a solution. But you marked the answer as accepted, so most probably, you won't get other answers.