# how to reinstall Asus notebook using Recovery DVD?

Tags: windows-vista, reinstall

a friend of mine asked to reinstall his Asus notebook. He didn't want Vista anymore so I installed XP. Re-partitioned the hdd (no more recovery partition). Everything went fine except I cannot make LAN card work. I created a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/231287/which-lan-driver-should-i-use-for-asus-f5z) for that. And I talked to Asus help desk but it didn't help so we decided to go back to Vista.

I have the original Recovery DVD for his notebook. With files like ASUS.SWM and ASUS2.SWM. But I do not know how to use this DVD to reinstall his notebook.

Did I mention that his DVD drive mostly doesn't work?

## Update1

I tried to boot from it but got a message:

```
Windows could not start becuase the following file si missing or corrupt: 
<windows root>\system32\hal.dll Please reinstall a copy of the above file.
```

Comment: helpful halfway competent IT friend FAIL

Comment: Those DVDs are specific to computer models.

Comment: @digitxp: I have the notebook and its recovery DVD

Comment: Can't you boot from the recovery DVD?

Comment: @Nifle: DVD driver doesn't work at all times but more importantly there is an error. See update1 for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Creating Windows OEM recovery DVDs with Windows AIK](http://rmencia.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/creating-windows-oem-recovery-dvds-with-windows-aik-part-1/).